# How to extend the Bolt CLI Interface Nut?

Tags: bolt-cms

Is there a recommended way to extend the nut interface of bolt cms?

I would like to implement an extension for bolt which is best triggered from commandline but couldn't found any kind of documentation about this matter.

My current idea is to just edit the app/nut file and load my own BaseCommand subclass but before that I would like to know if there is another intended way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, there is.  Well, there will be...

Currently it is committed to master and will be in Bolt 2.0.  You can see the [draft documentation](https://github.com/GawainLynch/bolt-docs/blob/bcfa9438c46355b9fd5922a6fb23c9b92e74a730/source/extensions-nut-commands.md) that I wrote that explains the process...  Really simple :-)

Comment: Thank you! Does the second step work in bolt cms 1.6.9?

Comment: No, but if you backport https://github.com/bolt/bolt/commit/fa77e2b3e0dc1a3762ed0c5f8115d391f905a6f1 you might have some luck